# extracting data from .idx & .fs5

Tags: database

I have  database files in format .idx and .fs5 which I would like to extract data from.

I am not so sure of the database format but the vendor of the software which generates these is Exact [software for excellence]

Each table (or object) seems to have a separate pair of files, such as Debt4.FS5 and Debt4.IDX.

Any ideas on how to extract this data?

I have tried opening this file using text editor but the data is unreadable and disorganized